# does highlight.js check syntax as well

Tags: highlight.js

In addition to highlighting syntax (which I suppose means indentation, color etc.), does `highlight.js` check syntax as well. For eg. if I write the following code in `javascript`

```
function {
}
```

Would `highlight.js` show error that the function name is missing. I know that `ace.js` does this. I want to replace `ace.js` with `highlight.js`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Highlight.js does not check syntax, it only highlights code (with pattern matching).  Often incorrect syntax is simply ignored, or could cause your code to be highlighted funny.

It MIGHT be possible to write a 3rd party grammar that did have some ability to detect (and highlight) syntax errors, but this is not something the core library is interested in doing.

[Disclaim: I'm the current Highlight.js maintainer.]